# Sending data from ReactJs (using fetch API) to nodeJs server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, post, fetch

I am sending json data from react application using fetch API but in server I'm getting req.body as empty.What's the problem I don't know

Here is my code[React code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH8Xu.png)

```js
import './App.css';

function App() {

  function handleClick() {
    // Send data to the backend via POST
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/message', {  // Enter your IP address here
   
      method: 'POST', 
      header:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({name:"ROHIT"}) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header

    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      TO DO App by Rohit Satpute
           <button  onClick={handleClick} style={{
    }}>
      Send data to backend
    </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[Server Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiKVU.png)

```js
const express=require('express');
const cors=require('cors');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const MySchema=require('./myschema.js');

const app=express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/message',(req,res)=>{
   
    console.log(req.body);
   
    res.json("rohit");
})

app.listen(8000,()=>{
    console.log("server is running on port 8000");
})
```

I tried to find in what format does the fetch API is sending data to server.But in req of server it is nowhere.

Comment: Please, put your code as text in your question, not a image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three mistakes in your code that are needed to be corrected.

1. In the fetch api you need to use `headers` instead of `header`.
   for example:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:8545/message', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ name: 'Rohit' }),
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((res) => console.log(res));
```

2: You cannot access req.body without using the

```
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));
```

3: You need to whitelist your IP in the cors origin or you can allow access to every request using *. For example:

```
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(
    cors({
        origin: '*',
    })
);
```